# Can we convert 3dm file to stl or obj file using opennurbs c++ sdk

Tags: stl, opennurbs

I am looking for how can we use opennurbs c++ sdk to convert 3dm file format to stl or obj file format. I have already tried looking its documentation but got nothing much helpful.

documentation link [http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/#opennurbs][1]

another link: [http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/opennurbs/home][1]

Is it possible to convert 3dm file format to stl or obj file format using some API of opennurbs sdk or any other sdk. If yes then which API or sdk can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

openNURBS by itself only supports Rhino's 3DM file format. The 3DM file format can support both mesh and NURBS geometry, but STL only supports meshes. OBJ can support both.

You can use [Rhino](http://www.rhino3d.com) to open the 3DM file and save as OBJ or STL. Rhino also includes a robust mesher that can convert the NURBS geometry into a mesh for STL output.

You might also consider Okino's [PolyTrans](http://www.okino.com/conv/conv.htm?gclid=CMqyu-nkt88CFYWFfgodg6UEcA) software for doing file conversions automatically.

Comment: thanx for your response but I want a opensource sdk through which I can convert 3DM to STL